# Fubini theorem question

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be Lebesgue measurable nonnegative functions on $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $A_y=\{x:f(x) \geq y\}$ Let $F(y)=\int_{A_y} g(x)dx$.  Prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^\infty F(y)dy$.  I know this has to do with Fubini's theorem but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Hint: if $H(x,y) = 1$ when $f(x) \ge y$ and $0$ otherwise,
$$\int_0^\infty F(y)\ dy = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty H(x,y) g(x) \ dx\ dy$$  What is $\int_0^\infty H(x,y)\ dy$?

Comment: You might try to read again Robert's hint, s-l-o-w-l-y.

Comment: Say $f(x)=7$. What are $H(x,0)$, $H(x,2)$, $H(x,6)$ and $H(x,9)$? What is the function $y\mapsto H(x,y)$? Now what is $\int_0^\infty H(x,y)dy$?

Comment: Is it f(x)?  I think I see it

Comment: If you *see it* (which I hope), you might want to write yourself a solution and to post it here. After a while, you may even accept it... :-)

Comment: thank you.  I got a solution

Answer (score -2):

recall [Fubini’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and apply to couple of function $(f(x|t) ,p(t))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is not clear how your answer will help solve the problem. Adding in more detail would be helpful.